# Choppy Audio with Naudio and TCP Stream. Buffer Full Exception

Tags: c#, tcp, naudio

I am attempting to stream audio using Naudio over a TCP connection. The problem is the audio sounds choppy. I believe this is because I am getting an exception saying the buffer is full when I try to add samples to the bufferedwaveprovider.

I have tried increasing the buffer size however the result remains unchanged.

-----CLIENT CODE-----

```
    public TcpClient client;
    public WaveOut waveplayer = new WaveOut();
    public BufferedWaveProvider bwp = new BufferedWaveProvider(new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1));
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 16];

    public Form1()
    {
        bwp.BufferLength = 1024 * 16;
        waveplayer.Init(bwp);
        waveplayer.Play();
    }

    public void audio()
    {
        try
        {
            client = new TcpClient(textBox1.Text.ToString(), 8001);
            NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                ns.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                bwp.AddSamples(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

-----SERVER CODE------

```
    public NAudio.Wave.WaveInEvent sourcestream = null;
    public TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8001);
    public TcpClient client;
    public NetworkStream ns;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        sourcestream = new NAudio.Wave.WaveInEvent();
        sourcestream.DeviceNumber = 0;            
        sourcestream.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1);
        sourcestream.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs>(audioDataAvailable);
        sourcestream.StartRecording();
    }

    public void acceptclients()
    {
        listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8001);
        listener.Start();
        client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        ns = client.GetStream();
    }

    void audioDataAvailable(object sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (client.Connected)
            {
                ns.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.Buffer.Length);
                ns.Flush();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
```

Here is the exact error I recieve

"System.InvalidOperationException: Buffer full at NAudio.Wave.BufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're getting a buffer full exception, that means audio is arriving faster than you are playing it. You either need a larger buffer size, or to throttle audio before downloading it.

You also should use `e.BytesRecorded`, not `e.Buffer.Length` on the server side. That might also account for the issue you are seeing.

Another bug is that you should examine the number of bytes read from `ns.Read` and use that number when calling `bwp.AddSamples`

Comment: I tried using the bytes recorded and I am still seeing this issue.

Comment: I also tried increasing the buffer size to ~1GB but I still get the buffer full exception. I don't understand why the player is not playing the data fast enough. I would think that since I started playing before I started reading from the network stream that this would be sufficient. 

Should I start looking into compressing the audio before sending it?

Comment: I think I've seen where the problem is - you're assuming you always read a full buffer full of data from the network stream on the client side.

Comment: Changed the code to this and it got everything working. Thanks for the help!

int brx = ns.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
bwp.AddSamples(buffer, 0, brx);